# Creating Large Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

How can I create a large matrix in R or how can I zip a large matrix into some object?

```
y <- matrix(rnorm(2e4*2e4),1:20000,1:20000)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size "..." Gb
```

How is it possible to allocate this matrix?

Comment: I've voted to close this since it isn't clear what your problem is.  Do need want help with how to install the `bigmemory` package, or a recommendation on how to deal with big datasets?

Comment: For what it's worth, using 64-bit R, installing more RAM, and reading http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html will get you a long way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a huge fan of the `bigmemory` package and I am a Windows user.
To use the package I first chose to stay with R 2.15 as it still has a functional Windows version of `bigmemory` package available on CRAN. For R 3.0 I had to compile that old version to work with my big matrices.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why I'm giving this a serious answer but here goes...

1.I can install `bigmemory` just fine. Perhaps if you are having problems you should share the error message, your environment and OS, and then ask for help on that instead.

2.Perhaps this is just an example:

```
  y <- outer(1:20000,1:20000)
  Error: cannot allocate vector of size "..." Gb
```

but do you really want to do this? Couldn't you refactor your code to iterate/resample a smaller matrix many times or read the data a bit at a time,  to wit...

3.Have you considered using RSQlite? It's super easy to install and especially now with the `dplyr` package is very user friendly.

Comment: y <- outer(1:20000,1:20000) was just an example. I'm working with large matrixes. And the problem I have by install.packages("bigmemory") is that R cannot find the particular package in CRAN. You can check, if you don't believe me.

Comment: @And `bigmemory` is on CRAN, but doesn't run under Windows.  See http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html

Comment: As a good alternative of "bigmemory" is "ff" package.